# XSS vulnerabilities still exist even after using HTML Purifier

Tags: php, security, xss, code-injection, htmlpurifier

I'm testing one of my web application using [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com). To protect this project against XSS attacks, I used [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). This library is recommended by most of PHP developers for this purpose, but my scan results shows HTML Purifier can not protect us from XSS attacks completely. The scanner found two ways of attack by sending different harmful inputs:

1. `1<img sRc='http://attacker-9437/log.php?` (See HTML Purifier result [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate%5D=colgroup%3A%0D%0Ath%3A%0D%0Atd%3A%0D%0Aiframe%3Asrc%0D%0A&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=1%3Cimg%20sRc%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fattacker-9437%2Flog.php%3F&submit=Submit))
2. `1"onmouseover=vVF3(9185)"` (See HTML Purifier result [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate%5D=colgroup%3A%0D%0Ath%3A%0D%0Atd%3A%0D%0Aiframe%3Asrc%0D%0A&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=1%22onmouseover%3DvVF3%289185%29%22&submit=Submit))

As you can see results, HTML Purifier could not detect such attacks. I don't know if is there any specific option on HTML Purifier to solve such problems, or is it really unable to detect these methods of XSS attacks.
Do you have any idea? Or any other solution?

Comment: `1` isn't XSS.  `2` is safe unless you misuse the purifier (you should never put user content inside attributes).

Comment: `1` that is right, it is HTML injection actually. `2` is used to print user searched term in the value of text box. Do you have any idea for these 2 problem?

Comment: `2` should be entirely mitigated with `htmlspecialchars()` (this will escape the quotation marks). It's generally not something you should feed HTML Purifier - HTML Purifier is for the full HTML, not for text in HTML attributes. (You could, though, build your HTML without `htmlspecialchars()` and _then_ run the entire document through HTML Purifier before outputting it. HTML Purifier will then strip the "onmouseover" from any tag it happens to be on.)

Comment: See http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?html=<img+src%3D""onmouseover%3DvVF3%289185%29""%2F>&submit=Submit for an example of your `2` when purified _within its HTML context_.

Answer (score 2):

*(This is a late answer since this question is becoming the place duplicate questions are linked to, and previously some vital information was only available in comments.)*

HTML Purifier is a contextual HTML sanitiser, which is why it seems to be failing on those tasks.

Let's look at why in some detail:

### `1<img sRc='http://attacker-9437/log.php?`

You'll notice that HTML Purifier **closed this tag** for you, leaving only an image injection. An image is a perfectly valid and safe tag (barring, of course, current image library exploits). If you want it to throw away images entirely, consider adjusting the HTML Purifier whitelist by setting [HTML.Allowed](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Allowed).

That the image from the example is now loading a URL that belongs to an attacker, thus giving the attacker the IP of the user loading the page (and nothing else), is a tricky problem that HTML Purifier wasn't designed to solve. That said, you *could* write a HTML Purifier attribute checker that runs after purification, but before the HTML is put back together, like this:

```
// a bit of context
$htmlDef = $this->configuration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$image   = $htmlDef->addBlankElement('img');

// HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_CheckURL is a custom class you've supplied, 
// and checks the URL against a white- or blacklist:
$image->attr_transform_post[] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_CheckURL();
```

The `HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_CheckURL` class would need to have a structure like this:

```
class HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_CheckURL extends HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform
{
    public function transform($attr, $config, $context) {
        $destination = $attr['src'];
        if (is_malicious($destination)) {
            // ^ is_malicious() is something you'd have to write
            $this->confiscateAttr($attr, 'src');
        }
        return $attr;
    }
}
```

Of course, it's difficult to do this 'right':

- if this is a live check with some web-service, this will slow purification down to a crawl
- if you're keeping a local cache you run risk of having outdated information
- if you're using heuristics ("that URL looks like it might be malicious based on indicators x, y and z"), you run risk of missing whole classes of malicious URLs

### `1"onmouseover=vVF3(9185)"`

HTML Purifier assumes the context your HTML is set in is a `<div>` (unless you tell it otherwise by setting [HTML.Parent](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Parent)).

If you just feed it an attribute value, it's going to assume you're going to output this somewhere so the end-result looks like this:

```
...
<div>1"onmouseover=vVF3(9185)"</div>
...
```

That's why it appears to not be doing anything about this input - it's harmless in this context. You might even not want to strip this information in that context. I mean, we're talking about this snippet here on stackoverflow, and that's valuable (and not causing a security problem).

Context matters. Now, if you instead feed HTML Purifier *this* snippet:

```
<div class="1"onmouseover=vVF3(9185)"">foo</div>
```

...suddenly you can see [what it's made to do](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate%5D=colgroup%3A%0D%0Ath%3A%0D%0Atd%3A%0D%0Aiframe%3Asrc%0D%0A&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%221%22onmouseover%3DvVF3%289185%29%22%22%3Efoo%3C%2Fdiv%3E&submit=Submit):

```
<div class="1">foo</div>
```

Now it's removed the injection, because in *this* context, it would have been malicious.

### What to use HTML Purifier for and what not

So now you're left to wonder what you should be using HTML Purifier for, and when it's the wrong tool for the job. Here's a quick run-down:

- you should use `htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')` (or whatever your encoding is) if you're outputting into a HTML document and *aren't interested in preserving HTML at all* - it's unnecessary overhead and it'll let some things through
- you should use HTML Purifier if you want to output into a HTML document and allow formatting, e.g. if you're a message board and you want people to be able to format their messages using HTML
- you should use `htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')` if you're outputting into a HTML **attribute** (HTML Purifier is not [meant for this use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26376081/245790))

You can find some more information about sanitising / escaping by context [in this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37641037/245790).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>All the HTML purifier seems to be doing, from the brief look that I gave, was HTML encode certain characters such as `<`, `>` and so on. However there are other means of invoking JS without using the normal HTML characters:</strike>

```
javascript:prompt(1)  // In image tags
src="http://evil.com/xss.html"  // In iFrame tags
```

Please review comments (by @pinkgothic) below.

---

#### Points below:

1. This would be HTML injection which does effectively lead to XSS. In this case, you open an `<img>` tag, point the `src` to some non-existent file which in turn raises an error. That can then be handled by the `onerror` handler to run some JavaScript code. Take the following example:

`<img src=x onerror=alert(document.domain)>`

The entrypoint for this it generally accompanied by prematurely closing another tag on an input. For example (URL decoded for clarity):

```
GET /products.php?type="><img src=x onerror=prompt(1)> HTTP/1.1
```

This however, is easily mititgated by HTML escaping meta-character (i.e. `<`, `>`).

2. Same as above, except this could be closing off an HTML attribute instead of a tag and inserting its own attribute. Say you have a page where you can upload the URL for an image:

`<img src="$USER_DEFINED">`

A normal example would be:

`<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`

However, inserting the above payload, we **cut off** the `src` attribute which points to a non-existent file and inject an `onerror` handler:

`<img src="1"onerror=alert(document.domain)">`

This executes the same payload mentioned above.

---

#### Remediation

This is heavily documented and tested in multiple places, so I won't go into detail. However, the following two articles are great on the subject and will cover all your needs:

1. https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/
2. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Actually, the `onerror` attribute is stripped by HTML Purifier (in fact, any non-whitelisted attribute is stripped by default), so your #1 is already mitigated by HTML Purifier. The attack described in the OP is a CSRF(-related) attack, and HTML Purifier does not protect against those (and cannot, because there's no way to differentiate between a good and a bad URL other than with either heuristics and/or checking the URL against a database, which in can be a prohibitive overhead and allow DoSing if added to the processing - though HTML Purifier allows customisation, so you could add it).

Comment: Generally speaking, HTML Purifier is an *HTML parser* that uses a *whitelist* to protect users. It's actually a very powerful tool that can be configured to be more lenient or more safe than its defaults, depending on what you need (see http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html). It's also often not what people need -->

Comment: HTML Purifier is the right tool for the job if you need to purify HTML documents or HTML document snippets that need to safely be displayed as HTML. It's the wrong tool when you just want to preserve the data (htmlspecialchars or SQL injection mitigation are more useful here, depending on context), or want to secure the contents of attributes only but don't run the entire document through HTML Purifier.

Comment: @pinkgothic - Then if that's the case, HTML Purifier is fine. Once again, this  is explaining it at a higher level beyond HTML Purifier because I do not know how it works and what it does. The user received an XSS vulnerability alert, and the above generally explains how to go about it and how it can occur.

Comment: Hey, Juxhin, I realise this is me being late to the party, and I apologise, but could you edit your answer so it doesn't claim HTML Purifier is essentially just `htmlspecialchars()` (first paragraph)? I've addressed this in my old comments but it's still in the answer. Since people are linking to this as a reference question, could you fix it even though it's a year later?

Comment: @pinkgothic Apologies for the delay--updating my answer shortly.