# How do I validate HTML and make sure it does not contain any Javascript using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, htmlpurifier

Does anyone know How do I validate (not sanitize) my HTML and make sure it does not contain any Javascript using PHP? If it does contain Javascript, I will just redirect to an error page.

I have tried using HTMLPurifier but it only seems to sanitize unless I'm missing something?

If my sample attack =

```
" onMouseOver="alert(1);
```

HTMLPurifer will allow that and in turn, it will be entered into the database. This means if I output it and fail to sanitize, I might have a problem.

If you visit:
[XSS vulnerabilities still exist even after using HTML Purifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317137/xss-vulnerabilities-still-exist-even-after-using-html-purifier)
It talks about HTML Purifier as a "HTML Purifier is a contextual HTML sanitiser".

which is great and I will definitely use but I'm looking for something to validate my input before I enter it into the Database and not sanitize it on my output (which I will do of course but this is a different action).

I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Thanks

Comment: You can certainly configure HTMLPurifier to exclude online event attributes.

Comment: If I set HTML.AllowedElements = [] and HTML.AllowedAttributes = [], " onMouseOver="alert(1); still gets through? maybe I'm setting the wrong setting?

Comment: All though I was wanting validation rather than sanitizing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSS vulnerabilities still exist even after using HTML Purifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317137/xss-vulnerabilities-still-exist-even-after-using-html-purifier)

Comment: This talks about sanitizing your output which is great but I'm trying to find out about validation. What I really want to do is kick them away if they attempt to do anything malicious. Thanks for the reference though.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't contain any JavaScript. It would only contain JavaScript if you were to insert it into an HTML attribute in such a way that `onMouseOver` becomes an HTML attribute instead of just a bit of free text. Context matters.

Comment: Trying to stop people submitting stuff that looks like an attack risks false positives.  I wouldn't worry about it. Focus on the output escaping instead.